# Load data local infile if each of the lines has different pattern

Tags: php, mysql, csv

I am trying to import a large csv file to the database using load data local infile query.It is working fine if all the lines of  the csv file have the same structure.But in my scenario few line have different pattern and few lines have some other pattern.

The csv file looks like this-
tablename : Sales

With the specified column names in the first line of the csv

Name:Sales.csv

Path : /Path_to_the_file/Sales.csv

```
Transaction_date,Product,Price,Payment_Type,Name,City,State,Country,Account_Created,Last_Login,Latitude,Longitude
1/25/09 16:17,Product1,1200,Amex,Mareike,Cumming                     ,GA,United States,1/24/09 18:06,2/7/09 11:28,34.20722,-84.14028
1/15/09 10:37,Product1,1200,Visa,lamia,Little Compton              ,RI,United States,6/28/08 11:04,2/7/09 12:00,41.51,-71.17167
1/20/09 15:28,Product1,1200,Visa,Madhu,Centennial                  ,CO,United States,12/2/06 23:24,2/7/09 15:18,39.57917,-104.87639
1/28/09 18:00,Product1,"13,000",Visa,sandhya,Centennial                  ,CO,United States,12/2/06 23:24,2/7/09 15:18,39.57917,-104.87639
1/29/09 5:06,Product1,1200,Amex,Kimberly,Herndon                     ,VA,United States,1/23/08 10:05,2/7/09 15:23,38.96944,-77.38639
1/6/09 18:53,Product1,1200,Visa,Tania,Vista                       ,CA,United States,1/5/09 22:37,2/7/09 15:48,33.2,-117.24167
```

Mysql query looks like this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Path_to_the_file/Sales.csv'
                                  INTO TABLE  Sales
                                  FIELDS TERMINATED by ','
                                  LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'
                                  IGNORE 1 ROWS
```

The output from the query :
For the Fourth row it considers 13 as one field and 000 as another field. Please help me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try to process the file using php.

```
$tmp_file = /path/to/csv;
$file = fopen($tmp_file,"r");
        $ar = fgetcsv($file);

        while(! feof($file))
              {
              $r = fgetcsv($file);


              $col1 = $r[0]; //Transaction date
              $col2 = $r[1]; //Product

             //insert to table here.

         }

fclose($file);
```

Or Can you try this

```
LOAD DATA
          LOCAL INFILE '/Path_to_the_file/Sales.csv'
          INTO TABLE Sales
          FIELDS
            TERMINATED BY ','
            ENCLOSED BY '"'
            ESCAPED BY '"'
          LINES
            TERMINATED BY '\n'
          IGNORE 0 LINES
```

Comment: I tried to import the file using fgetcsv so that i can manipulate the data while importing the file to the database.But that process is time consuming if the file size goes on increases say 25Mb.If i run the file in my local it will be 45 minutes if the file size goes on increases if i run the file in the server it will take more than 1.5 hrs to load the file.At that time connection will be termintated

Comment: I  tried this.This query returns only one row as a output that too it escapes the field named Transaction_date in the csv.

Comment: The above mentioned query helped a lot for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I edited the above answer little bit and i refered 
http://kedar.nitty-witty.com/blog/load-delimited-data-csv-excel-into-mysql-server this tutorial.Finally the query works for me.Thanks to Jeffrey Hitosis.

```
LOAD DATA
          LOCAL INFILE 'Path_to_the_file'
          INTO TABLE table_name
          FIELDS
            TERMINATED BY ','
           OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
            ESCAPED BY '"'
          LINES
            TERMINATED BY '\n'
          IGNORE 1 LINES
```

This query works with all csv files with or without enclosed by quoted characters in it.